# How are escape characters counted towards the length of a string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I used to thought escape character `\` count as 1 towards a string's length.

```
y = "I\'m tired"
  print(len(y))
```

The result for `print(Len(y))`= `9`, which makes sense.(`imtired` has 7 characters, `'` counts as 1, `\` counts as 1). However, when I test out below coding, the result is `7` instead of `8`(`water` has 5 characters, `\`escape character counts as 1, `""` counts as 2). I was really confused by this.

```
m = "wa\"t\"er"
print(len(m))
```

Comment: My python says that `"wa\"t\"er"` has `7` characters, as I expected. What python are you using?

Comment: Python3, ahhh I am sorry it was a mistake. I was testing "water" first to check the length and set the variable as n and then the amswer of print(Len(n)) is 5. My bad!

Answer (score 2):

Escape characters *cannot possibly* be counted, *because they are not part of the string* to begin with. That is the *whole point* of escape characters, and it is in fact the *reason* why they are called "escape" characters: because the allow you to "escape" the contents of the string into a different level where you can control the processing of the next character, by either treating it specially (e.g. in `\n`) or making sure it is *not* treated specially (e.g. in `\'` or the very special case of `\\` where the first backslash is a special character telling the parser to treat the next character speciall, namely by treating it not specially as it otherwise would).

The term "escape" comes from in-band communication protocols, where the content and control share the data stream. An escape sequence or escape character allows you to switch from the content to the control.

The reason why `"I'm tired"` (which is an alternative and 100% identical way to write your string) has a length of 9, is because … well … it has 9 characters:

1. <kbd>I</kbd>
2. <kbd>'</kbd>
3. <kbd>m</kbd>
4. <kbd>SPACE</kbd>
5. <kbd>t</kbd>
6. <kbd>i</kbd>
7. <kbd>r</kbd>
8. <kbd>e</kbd>
9. <kbd>d</kbd>

Likewise, the string `"wa\"t\"er"`, which is just a convoluted and less readable way of writing the exactly equivalent `'wa"t"er'` has 7 characters:

1. <kbd>w</kbd>
2. <kbd>a</kbd>
3. <kbd>"</kbd>
4. <kbd>t</kbd>
5. <kbd>"</kbd>
6. <kbd>e</kbd>
7. <kbd>r</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Escape characters are not counted in `len()`.

```
y = "I\'m tired"
```

`len()` output for above is 9 including the space. `\` is not counted.

```
m = "wa\"t\"er"
```

has a length of 7 -> `'water'`(5) + two double quotes (2).

Comment: Gotcha! Thanks! the result of print(Len(m)) is 7, I was mistaken it with another answer